# Create new dataframe from main dataframe based on condition of column value (without using .ix)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master dataframe in which contains players' data (containing all-stars and non-all-stars), and I would like to create a second dataframe that contains data only of all-stars players. The main reason is to have a sense of baseline stats of all-stars players.

The master dataframe looks like this [dataframe snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXSUJ.png), where 'allStar' is what I want to use as the condition.

I have found similar question in this site but the only solution uses .ix which I have a problem calling. My attempt:

```
fuStars = playersAS.ix[(playersData['allStar'] == 1)]
```

the error says:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'`

Comment: Is the dataframe name playersData?

Comment: I'll suggest you look at the Pandas Cheat Sheet. It has lots of great information. Here's the link: https://pandas.pydata.org/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

Comment: @SriswaroopKoundinya it is actually playersAS but the error persists after changing playersData into playersAS. Thanks for the cheat sheet btw.

Comment: No problem, Tan Jian Sean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can do the following:

```
fuStars = playersData[playersData.allStar == 1]
```

This will make a new DataFrame with all of the rows containing all-stars.